# Sorting nodes visually in Drupal

Tags: sorting, drupal, drupal-nodes

I have created a photo gallery for several web sites using CCK.  I created a new content type and added a numeric select list field that allows the client to change the order of the photos in the gallery (views with a jquery lightbox).

The problem is that there are now too many photos to manage the sort easily.  The only way for the client to change the sort order is to edit each photo node individually.

Is there some sort of drag and drop sorting that I utilize to give my clients a GUI interface to sort these nodes?

I had considered Nodequeue, but I thought there might be a better solution.

Answer (score 4):

A nodequeue is probably your best bet (remember that you can also do a view over a nodequeue, which makes them a little easier to use).

If your gallery is a content type, and a photo is a content type, then you can have your gallery noderef the photos.  Set it up so that the noderef uses autocomplete text fields, and you can then drag-and-drop the ordering on the gallery edit page.

Comment: I have not used Node Reference before.  If I went this route, would I have to create as many fields within the gallery content type as photos I want to show?  (1-1 relationship between photos and custom fields)

Comment: No, noderefs are just like any other field.  You can set the number of values for the field to be unlimited, or set an upper limit if you want/need.

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like a prime case scenario for [Draggable Views](http://drupal.org/project/draggableviews). It takes a little bit of setting up, you have to make a new page (in your current view) that is used only for administrative sorting, but once done it should work perfectly as you are describing.

Comment: I'm going to check this out.  Thanks.